# Maclaurin expansion disappearing fractions?

Tags: taylor-expansion

I'm trying to understand the examples in my book but I'm totally confused.

With the Maclaurin series with rest as big O notation. Further explained in the book;
$$\ln(1+x) = x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{x^n}{n}+\mathcal{O}(x^{n+1})$$

I understand this definition. However, when another example explains how to decide the Maclaurin series of $\ln(1+2x^2)$ of order $3$, they proceed;
$$\ln(1+2x^2)=\ln(1+u)=u+\mathcal{O}(u^2)=2x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^4)$$

I understand the variable switch and the big O magic in the end, but why do they skip fractions? Where is $-\frac{u^2}{2}+\frac{u^3}{3}$? Would make more sense if it was to the $1st$ order...

Comment: This would be first order in $u$, but since $u = 2x^{2}$ then including $-\frac{u^{2}}{2} = -\frac{4x^{4}}{2}$ would be to order $4$, and you only want to order $3$.

Comment: Hint: $u=2{x^2}$. So what is the next term expressed with $x?$

Answer (score 2):

The terms would be as follows: $$\ln(1+2x^2)=\ln(1+u)=u-\frac{u^2}2+\frac{u^3}3-\mathcal{O}(u^4)=2x^2-\frac{4x^4}{2}+\frac{8x^6}{3}-\mathcal{O}(x^8)$$ So to $3^{rd}$ order in $x$, this is why they ended the series where they did. This happens because $u=O(x^2)$, so you only need to expand $u$ until order $\frac n2$ to get an order $n$ expansion for $x$. Here $n=3$, so you expand up to order $3/2$ in $u$ (of course you only use integer coefficients, so stop at $1$).

Answer (score 0):

The general formula gives (after substituting $2x^2$ for $x$)

$$\ln(1+2x^2) = 2x^2-\frac{(2x^2)^2}{2}+\frac{(2x^2)^3}{3}-...+(-1)^{n-1}\frac{(2x^2)^n}{n}+\mathcal{O}({(x^2)^{n+1}}).$$

To get the development to order $3$, take $n=1$ and

$$\ln(1+2x^2) = 2x^2+\mathcal{O}(x^4).$$

Comment: @JohnDoe: thanks for pointing. I have reformulated.